# Bulk emails created with the APi delivered to 0 recipients

Tags: civimail, api

I'm using the API to send a bulk email each week to all our members.  This is the code:
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$approval_date = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentTime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
$schedule_date = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

```
$params = [
    'scheduled_date' => $schedule_date,
    'approver_id' => 396,
    'approval_date' => $approval_date,
    'from_name'          => "Jack Donohue",
    'from_email'         => "info@crw.org",
    'replyto_email'      => "donohue.jack@gmail.com",
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body_text' => $text,
    'body_html' => $html,
    'name' => 'weekly email',
    'created_id' => 396,
    'header_id' => '',
    'footer_id' => '',
    'groups' => [
        'include' => [
            '0' => 128,     // Current members
        ],
        'exclude' => [
        ],
    ],
    'mailings' => [
        'include' => [],
        'exclude' => [],
    ],
    /*
    'options' => [
        'force_rollback' => 0,
    ],
    */
    'api.MailingRecipients.get' => [
        'mailing_id' => '$value.id',
        'api.contact.getvalue' => [
            'return' => 'display_name',
        ],
        'api.email.getvalue' => [
            'return' => 'email',
        ],
    ],
];

try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'create', $params);
}
catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // Handle error here.
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    log_message( $errorMessage);return;
}
```

The email is created, scheduled to be sent, and is sent, but the report says it was sent to 0 recipients

Delivery Summary
Intended Recipients 2417
Successful Deliveries   0 (0.00%)

The only thing that looks odd is that the Sent By field in the table of emails is empty despite the fact that I set this in the parameters.

It's supposed to be sent out around 2 am each Thursday, and when it isn't I do reuse and send it manually which works fine.

Can you figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Jack Donohue